# Plush frame not aligning

Tags: css, alignment

I'm working on [3 frames in this codepen](https://codepen.io/ryanve/pen/MrNVQe) where a frame is a like a structural base shape. I'm testing each on 3 elements `span` `button` `input` which are reset via [preset classes](https://unpkg.com/@plangrid/structure@0.36.0/main.css). Elements using the `dense` and `basic` frames vertically align exactly whereas the `plush` frames are vertically misaligned. What's different about `plush` that's causing the alignment difference? What do I need to add normalize the alignment?

```
.frame-dense {
  border-image: none;
  border-radius: var(--radii-medium);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 28px;
  padding: 3px 11px;
}

.frame-basic {
  border-image: none;
  border-radius: var(--radii-medium);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 36px;
  padding: 7px 15px;
}

.frame-plush {
  border-image: none;
  border-radius: var(--radii-medium);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 48px;
  padding: 11px 23px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the top/bottom padding of `.frame-plush` to 13px instead of 11px like this:

```
.frame-plush {
  border-image: none;
  border-radius: var(--radii-medium);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 48px;
  padding: 13px 23px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that led me to realize the the `min-height` was too low. If I simply remove the `min-height` that also aligns them! I added an empty element test that made me find realize I seemingly do need `min-height` for that case. Follow-up https://stackoverflow.com/q/48469414/770127