# How to ensure empty span matches height of sibling

Tags: css, alignment, vertical-alignment

[On codepen I'm testing some frame classes](https://codepen.io/ryanve/pen/jYgpNo) on `span` `button` `input` and an empty `span`. In order to ensure the empty `span` matches the height of the others I'm using `calc` math give it `min-height` but this calculation seems to require knowing `line-height`. Is there a way to ensure the `min-height` without needing to know the `line-height`? Also I don't understand why the `vertical-align` `middle` aligns the empty one with the others while `baseline` doesn't. If anyone can explain that or suggest alternative that'd be awesome

```
.frame-apply {
  --sum-border: calc(2 * var(--frame-border-width, 0));
  --sum-padding-y: calc(2 * var(--frame-padding-y));

  border-image: none;
  border-radius: var(--radii-medium);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: var(--frame-border-width, 0);
  display: inline-block;

  /* Using middle aligns the empty one with the others
     I don't understand why it doesn't align correctly as baseline */
  vertical-align: middle;

  /* min-height only seems necssary to fill the empty one
     It'd be better to avoid needing to know line-height */
  min-height: calc(
    var(--sum-padding-y) +
    var(--sum-border) + 
    1em * var(--test-line)
  );

  min-width: 0;
  padding:
    var(--frame-padding-y)
    var(--frame-padding-x);  
}

.frame-dense {
  --frame-padding-y: 3px;
  --frame-padding-x: 11px;
  --frame-border-width: 1px;
}

.frame-basic {
  --frame-padding-y: 7px;
  --frame-padding-x: 15px;
  --frame-border-width: 1px;
}

.frame-plush {
  --frame-padding-y: 11px;
  --frame-padding-x: 23px;
  --frame-border-width: 1px;
}

/* Test values ideally all scale */
:root {
  --test-size calc(1rem * 14px / 16px);
  --test-line: 1.5;
}

.font-test {
  font-size: var(--test-size);
  line-height: var(--test-line); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix all the issue (min-height and alignment) is to rely on flexbox where all the elements will by default stretch to fill the height of their line:

```css
figure {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
figcaption {
  width:100%;
}

figure > * {
 margin-right:4px!important; /*to replace the default whitespace*/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@plangrid/structure@0.36.0/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@plangrid/structure@0.36.0/root.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@plangrid/paint@0.34.0/blending.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@plangrid/paint@0.34.0/live.css">
<style>
/*
Preset classes in HTML are from
https://unpkg.com/@plangrid/structure@0.36.0/main.css
https://stackoverflow.com/q/48469414/770127
*/

.frame-apply {
  --sum-border: calc(2 * var(--frame-border-width, 0));
  --sum-padding-y: calc(2 * var(--frame-padding-y));
  border-image: none;
  border-radius: var(--radii-medium);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: var(--frame-border-width, 0);
  min-width: 0;
  padding:
    var(--frame-padding-y)
    var(--frame-padding-x);  
}

.frame-dense {
  --frame-padding-y: 3px;
  --frame-padding-x: 11px;
  --frame-border-width: 1px;
}

.frame-basic {
  --frame-padding-y: 7px;
  --frame-padding-x: 15px;
  --frame-border-width: 1px;
}

.frame-plush {
  --frame-padding-y: 11px;
  --frame-padding-x: 23px;
  --frame-border-width: 1px;
}

/* Test values ideally all scale */
:root {
  --test-size calc(1rem * 14px / 16px);
  --test-line: 1.5;
}

.font-test {
  font-size: var(--test-size);
  line-height: var(--test-line); 
}
</style>
<figure class="preset-box mb3">
  <figcaption class="font-os mb1">frame-dense</figcaption>
  <span class="font-os font-test preset-box frame-apply frame-dense">span</span>
  <button class="font-os font-test preset-button frame-apply frame-dense ccc-black ggg-transparent bbb-black" type="button" disabled>button</button>
  <input class="font-os font-test preset-input frame-apply frame-dense ccc-black ggg-transparent bbb-black" value="input" disabled>
  <span class="font-os font-test preset-box frame-apply frame-dense "></span>
  <span class="font-os">&larr; empty</span>
</figure>
<figure class="preset-box mb3">
  <figcaption class="font-os mb1">frame-basic</figcaption>
  <span class="font-os font-test preset-box frame-apply frame-basic">span</span>
  <button class="font-os font-test preset-button frame-apply frame-basic ccc-black ggg-transparent bbb-black" type="button" disabled>button</button>
  <input class="font-os font-test preset-input frame-apply frame-basic ccc-black ggg-transparent bbb-black" value="input" disabled>
  <span class="font-os font-test preset-box frame-apply frame-basic"></span>
  <span class="font-os">&larr; empty</span>
</figure>
<figure class="preset-box mb3">
  <figcaption class="font-os mb1">frame-plush</figcaption>
  <span class="font-os font-test preset-box frame-apply frame-plush">span</span>
  <button class="font-os font-test preset-button frame-apply frame-plush ccc-black ggg-transparent bbb-black" type="button" disabled>button</button>
  <input class="font-os font-test preset-input frame-apply frame-plush ccc-black ggg-transparent bbb-black" value="input" disabled>
  <span class="font-os font-test preset-box frame-apply frame-plush"></span>
  <span class="font-os">&larr; empty</span>
</figure>
```